# Can a ForEach lambda expression have an optional return type

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Is there any way to get a `ForEach` lambda expression have an optional return type. Here a pseudo code example of what needs to be achieved:

```
string val = MyList.ForEach(listItem => { if(listItem == "yes" ){ return "found" }  });

if(val == "found"){ dosomething }
```

Comment: This isn't clear what you're trying to do, but I suspect you want either `.Any()` or `.All()` from LINQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `ForEach` is the wrong method for your result. Use `Any`:

```
bool found = MyList.Any(listItem => listItem == "yes");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks.